# Dfferentiate $y = x \log\sqrt{\sin(x^{2}+1)}$

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

=  $$x\log\left [ \sin(x^{2}+1) \right ]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Using property of log and then product rule we get,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}  =  \frac{1}{2}\left [ x\left ( \frac{1}{\sin(x^{2}+1)}\cos(x^{2}+1)2x \right )+\log(\sin(x^{2}+1)) \right ]$$
 $$dy/dx = x^{2}\cot(x^{2}+1)+\frac{\log(\sin(x^{2}+1))}{2}$$
This was my answer.
However the answer given is
$$(x^{2}\cot(x^{2}+1))+ \log \sqrt{\sin(x^{2}+1)}$$

Comment: MathJax hints:  putting a backslash before log, sin, and other common functions gives the right font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$ instead of log x which gives $log x$.  Enclosing the argument of \sqrt in braces extends the top bar over the whole argument, so \sqrt{x^2+1} gives $\sqrt{x^2+1}$.  It works in subscripts, superscripts, fractions, and everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same:
$$\frac{\log a}{2} = \frac12 \log a = \log(a^{1/2}) = \log(\sqrt a)$$

Comment: I know that but the answer i got was different from what was given.

Comment: Why? In what part differs?

Comment: Damn! You are right . Thank you very much . Maybe I was a bit ignorant .